# binning two dimensional data by its index in python

Tags: python, pandas, average, binning

How would I bin some data based on the index of the data, in python 3

Let's say I have the following data

```
1   0.5
3   0.6
5   0.7
6   0.8
8   0.9
10  1
11  1.1
12  1.2
14  1.3
15  1.4
17  1.5
18  1.6
19  1.7
20  1.8
22  1.9
24  2
25  2.1
28  2.2
31  2.3
35  2.4
```

how would I take this data and bin both columns such that each bin has n number of values in it, and average the numbers in each bin and output them. 
for example, if I wanted to bin the values by 4

I would take the first four data points:

```
1   0.5
3   0.6
5   0.7
6   0.8
```

and the averages of these would be: 3.75    0.65

I would continue down the columns by taking the next set of four, and so on
until I averaged all of the sets of four to get this:

```
3.75    0.65 
10.25   1.05
16      1.45
21.25   1.85
29.75   2.25
```

How can I do this using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on `numpy` `reshape`

```
pd.DataFrame([np.mean(x.reshape(len(df)//4,-1),axis=1) for x in df.values.T]).T
       0     1
0   3.75  0.65
1  10.25  1.05
2  16.00  1.45
3  21.25  1.85
4  29.75  2.25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "bin" the index into groups of 4 and call `groupby` in the index.

```
df.groupby(df.index // 4).mean()
       0     1
0   3.75  0.65
1  10.25  1.05
2  16.00  1.45
3  21.25  1.85
4  29.75  2.25
```